# SwiftUI - conditional rendering with if/else renders BOTH views

Tags: swiftui, ios-simulator

I have code that is similar to the following:

```
if let item = data.item, item.isPublished {
  Text("Published ")
} else {
  Button(
    action: handleTap,
    label: { Text("Tap to publish") }
  )
}
```

The `item` in my data model is `published`.

When I build and run on simulator (iPhone 14, iOS 16.4) "Published " is shown (as expected). However, when the user taps on the text view, the button action is invoked.

I don't see how this is possible -- am I missing something incredibly obvious?

When I build to my device, which is an iPhone, the code works as expected.

Comment: I didn't manage to reproduce the problem based on the snippet here. Could you provide a full MRE please?

Comment: I've seen this problem in another question, will try to find it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you or not. I also had this problem with iOS 16.4. The problem for me is when I work with the List view.

```swift
struct ProfileView: View {
    @State var isTapped = false

    var body: some View {
        List {
            if isTapped {
                Text("Hello")
            } else {
                Button("Tap me", action: { isTapped = true })
            }
            Section {
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Text("Reset and remove all data")
                        .foregroundColor(.negative)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After tapping on the button, the view change to `Text("Hello")`. But the button action is invoked if the user taps the `Text("hello")`.

After trying with my friend, we found that we must wrap the if condition inside the `Section` to make it work as expected.

```swift
struct ProfileView: View {
    @State var isTapped = false

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                if isTapped {
                    Text("Hello")
                } else {
                    Button("Tap me", action: { isTapped = true })
                }
            }
            Section {
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Text("Reset and remove all data")
                        .foregroundColor(.negative)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, in my case, it seems like if we have a `Section` in the `List` view, the other views also need to be wrapped inside `Section`.